# Map<String, Object> - Search Object and add certain values to a set

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, set

Following on from a previous question, I want to iterate over the Object values in my map, and if certain results found, add them to a Set/List then return that Set/List.

My code for Employer Class:

```
public class Employer {
    Map<String, NewHire> employee = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addEmployee(String fullName, String age, String location, String JobTitle) {
    NewHire newEmployee = new NewHire(age, location, JobTitle);
    this.employee.put(fullName, newEmployee);
}
```

Second Object code:

```
public class NewHire {
    private String age;
    private String location;
    private String jobTitle;
}

public NewHire(String aAge, String aLocation, String aJobTitle) {
    this.age = aAge;
     this.location = aLocation;
     this.jobTitle = aJobTitle;
}
```

And I have added the following:

```
Employer CompanyA = new Employer();
CompanyA.addEmployee("JohnSmith1", "22", "London", "Front Office");
CompanyA.addEmployee("JohnSmith2", "23", "Paris", "Service Desk");
CompanyA.addEmployee("JohnSmith3", "22", "Paris", "Service Desk");
CompanyA.addEmployee("JohnSmith4", "21", "New York", "HR");
```

I now want to add the following method:

```
public NewHire findAnEmployee(String jobTitle)
```

What I need the method to do is looks for all Employees that work in "Service Desk" for example, add them to a Set and return that Set.   And if nobody is found for that position, return a general message that states nobody was found that works there.

I am struggling to grasp how I can do this.

Comment: Why not return an empty set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given below is how you should implement your method in `Employer` class:

```
public Set<NewHire> findEmployees(String jobTitle) {
    Set<NewHire> result = new HashSet<NewHire>();
    for (Entry<String, NewHire> entry : employee.entrySet()) {
        NewHire newHire = entry.getValue();
        if (newHire.getJobTitle().equals(jobTitle)) {
            result.add(newHire);
        }
    }
    if (result.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Nobody is found for that position");
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Output:**

The output for `System.out.println(CompanyA.findEmployees("Service Desk"));` will be as follows:

```
[NewHire [age=22, location=Paris, jobTitle=Service Desk], NewHire [age=23, location=Paris, jobTitle=Service Desk]]
```

Assumptions:

1. You have already implemented `public` getters and setters in the class `NewHire`.
2. You have already implemented `toString()` method in the class `NewHire` as follows (this is the auto-generated code by eclipse):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "NewHire [age=" + age + ", location=" + location + ", jobTitle=" + jobTitle + "]";
}
```

**Additional notes:**

3. You should follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the variable, `CompanyA` should be named as `companyA`.
4. The name of the method should be self-descriptive e.g. the method name, `findAnEmployee` should be changed to `findEmployees` as you have mentioned, `What I need the method to do is looks for all Employees that work in "Service Desk" for example, add them to a Set and return that Set.`.

Comment: `Entry` is a typed object.  If you properly assign the types in your `for loop` as `Entry<String,NewHire>` you won't  have  to cast the `entry.getValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by @JohannesKuhn was a good one. Here is how it might be implemented.

```
    Set<NewHire> newEmp = findEmployees("Service Desk");
    if (!newEmp.isEmpty()) {
        newEmp.forEach(System.out::println);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No records found for job title");
    }
```

Prints (using the `toString` and `fullname` suggestions below)

```
JohnSmith3, 22, Paris, Service Desk
JohnSmith2, 23, Paris, Service Desk
```

And here is the method. It

- creates a stream of the map values (which are NewHire instances).
- filters on the job title.
- And collects them into a set.

```
    public Set<NewHire> findEmployees(String jobTitle) {
        return employee.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(emp->emp.jobTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(jobTitle))
             .collect(Collectors.toSet());      
    }
```

A couple of suggestions.

- Add fullname to the NewHire class.
- Change method name to `findEmployees`
- Override NewHire's toString method to return a string of pertinent info.
  e.g.

```
        public String toString() {
            return name + ", " + age + ", " + location + ", " + jobTitle;
        }
```

Comment: Other suggestion...If the method could return a collection..better to rename it to `findEmployees`

Comment: Good suggestion, I added it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Stream API:

```
public Set<NewHire> findAnEmployee(String jobTitle) {
        return employee.values().stream().filter(e -> e.getJobTitle().equals(jobTitle)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

```
CompanyA.findAnEmployee("Service Desk").stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

I implement an getJobTitle and toString Methot in NewHire class...